Sveltekit TypeScript NGINX not serve static files
On my local environment my worker serving correctly and my .ts files can find the static file with path.
src\lib\client\utilities\nsfw\nsfw.ts
this is my path for nsfw.
export async function loadModel() {
  // Importing nsfwjs only when needed
  const nsfwjs = await import('nsfwjs');
  const tf = await import('@tensorflow/tfjs');
  await tf.setBackend('cpu');
  await tf.ready();
  const nsfwClassifier = await nsfwjs.load('/models/mobilenet_v2/model.json');
  return nsfwClassifier;
}
export async function isNsfwContent(videoElement: HTMLVideoElement) {
  return new Promise<number>((resolve, reject) => {
    const worker = new Worker('../nsfwWorker.js', { type: 'module' });

    worker.onmessage = (event) => {
      const { nudityScore } = event.data;
      worker.terminate();
      resolve(nudityScore);
    };

    worker.onerror = (error) => {
      worker.terminate();
      reject(error);
    };

    const videoFrame = captureFrameFromVideo(videoElement);
    worker.postMessage({ videoFrame });
  });
}

function captureFrameFromVideo(videoElement: HTMLVideoElement): ImageData {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  canvas.width = videoElement.videoWidth;
  canvas.height = videoElement.videoHeight;
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  if (context) {
    context.drawImage(videoElement, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    return context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }

  throw new Error('Could not get 2D context from canvas');
}


let nsfwClassifier: any; // Declare nsfwClassifier outside functions

And tthis is the path and my worker.js
\static\nsfwWorker.js
import { loadModel } from '../src/lib/client/utilities/nsfw/nsfw.ts';

let nsfwClassifier=null;

self.onmessage = async (event) => {
  const { videoFrame } = event.data;

  if (!nsfwClassifier) {
    nsfwClassifier = await loadModel();
  }

  const predictions = await nsfwClassifier.classify(videoFrame, 3);
  const nudityScore = predictions.find(pred => pred.className === 'Porn')?.probability ?? 0;

  self.postMessage({ nudityScore });
};


this codes works fine on local environment but when i published it nsfw.ts getting 302,
i tried to server static files on nginx configuration but i couldn't find the either problem and solution.
I just want my .ts file can acces the path of worker.js
This is the error on live.
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

homeView.CF-kaEoG.js:2 Error checking for nudity: 
Event {isTrusted: true, type: 'error', target: Worker, currentTarget: Worker, eventPhase: 2, …}



i found the solution for my problem.
You need to change vite.config.ts.
Instead of changing all rollupoutput format just need to declare worker format as "ES",
worker: {
        format: "es"
      },

